# Unable to open Ganache locally deployed contract in remix.ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I have successfully deployed a solidity contract locally with Ganache.
I would now like to interact with it via http://remix.ethereum.org/

In the remix editor,I have selected the "web3 provider" and connected to my local Ganache at "http://127.0.0.1:7545"

[image]

I have inserted my contract's Address in the "At address" section, but I continually connect to the default "Ballot" contract provided by remix.
Can anyone help me connect to my locally deployed contract?

Comment: You need to paste the code for your contract into the editor and then choose the contract from the dropdown on the right.

Comment: I am using "import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol" statement in my locally deployed contract and I cannot import those into the remix editor.

Comment: Delete the `import` line and instead paste the code.

Comment: I have discovered a better way to import openZepplin in remix https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/is-it-possible-to-include-all-the-openzeppelin-library-files-on-remix